# Scapy windows - sniff() - 'log_runtime' is not defined

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scapy

I installed python 2.7 and scapy following the supported programs: pywin32, WinPcap, Pypcap and libdnet. I feel that it is important to say that my OS is windows 7.

When I am using the function sniff it appears to raise an error: http://prntscr.com/dbd79a. I have tried another scapy's function and classes as IP and sendp and it works fine, the problem is only on sniff.

I have tried several versions of scapy from many installations links and no change.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a bug in version 2.3.3 of scapy (uploaded on 18/10/16).
It will probably be fixed in the next version, in the meantime you can install the previous version by doing

```
pip install scapy==2.3.2
```

I checked in the commits and this bug wasnt in that version. However i havent tested it so it might contain other bugs (as 2.3.3 must have changed something for the better, atleast i hope it did), so if you must use 2.3.3 for some reason you can patch it around like this:

```
from scapy.arch.windows import compatibility
from scapy.all import log_runtime, MTU, ETH_P_ALL, PcapTimeoutElapsed, plist

compatibility.log_runtime = log_runtime
compatibility.MTU = MTU
compatibility.PcapTimeoutElapsed = PcapTimeoutElapsed
compatibility.ETH_P_ALL = ETH_P_ALL
compatibility.plist = plist

compatibility.sniff(1) # call the sniff function however you like
```